# The image in Django app not working

Tags: python, html, django

I created a `Python-Django` web application.I set an album_logo field in models.py file and I tried to upload an image url through python shell using the code

```
>>>from music.models import Album, Song
>>>Album.objects.all()
[]
>>>a = Album(artist="Taylor Swift", album_title="Red", genre=" Country", album_logo="http://carywebdesigns.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/www2.jpg")
>>>a.save()
>>>a.artist
'Taylor Swift'
>>>a.album_title
'Red'
>>>a.id
1
>>>a.pk
1
```

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Album(models.Model):
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    album_title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    genre = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    album_logo = models.CharField(max_length=1000)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.album_title + ' - ' + self.artist
```

And I run this codes using `python manage.py runserver`,I got the correct answer.But the image was not loaded.
And I have 2 template files.
index.html

```
{% if all_albums %}
    <h3>Here are all my Albums:</h3>
    <ul>
        {% for album in all_albums %}
        <li><a href="/music/{{ album.id }}/">{{ album.album_title }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <h3>You don't have any albums</h3>
{% endif %}
```

detail.html

```
<img src="{{ album.album_logo }}">

<h1>{{ album.album_title }}</h1>
<h3>{{ artist }}</h3>

<ul>
        {% for song in album.song_set.all %}
                <li>{{ song.song_title }} - {{ song.file_type }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
```

How can I solve this problem.Please help me.Thanks in advance..

Comment: how do you display the image? please share the template code

Answer (score 1):

For example you need to create the list of objects of `Album` model:

```
def listAlbum(request):
  album_list = Album.objects.all()
  return render(request, '/your/template.html', {'album_list':album_list})
```

in this case to show the image of objects in template it should look like this:

```
{% for a in album_list %}
   <img src="{{a.album_logo}}>
{% endfor %}
```

If you want to display detail object, then your view should look like this:

```
def detailAlbum(request, pk):
  album = Album.objects.get(pk=pk)
  return render(request, '/your/template.html', {'album':album})
```

In this case your template should looks like this:

```
<img src="{{a.album}}>
```

Hope it helps you